# Zendframe work Meta Data

Tags: html, zend-framework, metadata

Hello I know how to write Meta tags in Zend to beefined in an action like this:

```
// action body 

$this->_helper->layout()->getView()->headTitle(' Title Here') // setting the page title 
$this->view->headMeta()->appendName('keywords', 'heywords here'); 
$this->view->headMeta()->appendName('description', 'description here');
```

I will like to know the syntax for meta nofollow

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
$this->view->headMeta()->appendProperty('rel', 'nofollow');
```